# rails2 and aws-simple (simpledb): data cannot be deleted from amazon simpledb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

i am developing a ruby on rails (2.3.8) application with data storage amazon simpledb.
i am using the aws-sdb gem in the version aws-sdb (0.3.1)
there are a few bugs, but the problems are outlined in the comments of this tutorial from amazon: http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1242

i am wondering if it is a bug of the gem or maybe a proxy issue, but i cannot delete any data from simpledb. anyone else experienced this or has a clue?

```
>> t=Team.find(:first)
=> #<Team:0x329f718 @prefix_options={}, @attributes={"updated_at"=>Fri May 28 16:33:17 UTC 2010, "id"=>0}>
>> t.destroy
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK  readbody=true>
>> t=Team.find(:first)
=> #<Team:0x321ad38 @prefix_options={}, @attributes={"updated_at"=>Fri May 28 16:33:17 UTC 2010, "id"=>0}>
```

the team model is a normal ActiveResource Model, according to said tutorial.

```
   class Team < ActiveResource::Base
     self.site   = "http://localhost:8888" # Proxy host + port
     self.prefix = "/fb2010_dev/"       # SDB domain
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot delete any data from
>   simpledb. anyone else experienced this
>   or has a clue?

I faced an [issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=153871) with deletion if values contain special characters.